# working with threads - add to collection

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
List<int> data=new List<int>();
foreach(int id in ids){
    var myThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
    myThread.Start(id);
}


Work(){
}
```

Method Work does some processing on the received id and then adds the result to the data list? How can I add data to the collection from each thread? How would my code look like? thanks

Comment: You'd need to either manage locking the collection manually or use one of .NET's concurrent collections.  I'd recommend using Tasks for simple stuff like this, though, it neatly manages a lot of the complexity that Threads cause and will introduce some great programming concepts (if you don't know them already) that are really helpful.

Comment: As usual Jon thinks of the things I forget. You should definitely stick with his method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, I strongly suggest you use Parallel Extensions instead. For example:

```
var list = ids.AsParallel()
              .Select(Work)
              .ToList();
```

where `Work` is:

```
public int Work(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

so that it can receive the `id` appropriately. If you're not keen on the method conversion, you could add a lambda expression:

```
var list = ids.AsParallel()
              .Select(id => Work(id))
              .ToList();
```

Either way, this will avoid creating more threads than you really need, and deal with the thread safety side of things without you having to manage the locks yourself.

Comment: using AsParallel() works great but can I have more than 2 threds working in parallel

Comment: @Ryan: Absolutely. There are various ways of controlling the parallelization. Typically it will automatically scale itself to the number of cores you have available, but methods like WithDegreeOfParallelism can tweak things.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to protect your multithreaded access with a lock. Second, you need to pass the parameter to your thread (or use lambda which can capture the local variable; beware that if you capture loop variable, it will change the value during the loop, so you ought to have a local copy).

```
object collectionLock = new object();
List<int> data = new List<int>();

foreach (int id in ids)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Worker);
    t.Start(id);
}

void Worker(object o)
{
    int id = (int)o;
    lock(collectionLock)
    {
        data.Add(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: WRT: "You cannot capture the loop variable" (It actually can be captured -- it's just always the same variable ;-) To get around that ... detail ... I use `foreach (var _x in ...) { var x = _x; ... }`, where it matters.

Comment: @pst: Yes, I meant exactly this. The captured variable is reused in the loop, so capturing it and using the naive way would bring unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @pst: edited the answer to make it more clear. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass and retrieve data (using callbacks) from threads. See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52.aspx).

**Example:**

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static List<int> data = new List<int>();
        public static readonly object obj = new object();

        public void SomeMethod(int[] ids)
        {
            foreach (int id in ids)
            {
                Work w = new Work();
                w.Data = id;
                w.callback = ResultCallback; 
                var myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(w.DoWork));
                myThread.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void ResultCallback(int d)
        {        
            lock (obj)
            {        
                data.Add(d);
            }
        }

    }

    public delegate void ExampleCallback(int data); 
    class Work
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
        public ExampleCallback callback;

        public void DoWork()
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data={0}", Data);
            if (callback != null)
                callback(Data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good idea on not sharing data to avoid locking. But you're missing the results! The part where you add something to the `data` list!

Comment: If the threads are pushing the result into the list, there's no way to avoid locking/synchronization (maybe implicit). If the main thread is going to pull the data from the worker threads, it needs to know when the worker finishes work.